# Widget background not transparent when using QGraphicsView but transparent when using QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qgraphicsview, qt4.7

When I was using QGridLayout to display my widgets, only the widget was shown and the part of the image that was transparent was not shown. Now I switched to using QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView, and now my images have a gray background wherever they used to be transparent.

```
void Piece::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    string image = ":/images/" + color + piece + ".png";
    pixmap.load(image.c_str());
    //pixmap.setMask(pixmap.createMaskFromColor(QColor(240, 240, 240)));

    QPainter paint(this);
    paint.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap);
}
```

That's how the image is displayed on my widget. When I used the code,

```
layout->addWidget(0,0,1,1);
```

the background is transparent. But when I use,

```
scene->addWidget(piece);
```

The widget has a gray background. How can I make it transparent? The full code can be found here if necessary (probably won't be necessary): https://github.com/gsingh93/Chess

EDIT: I can't figure this problem out at all... I tried using setAutoFillBackground(false); but that didn't work. So my last hope was converting my whole class from a QWidget to a QGrahhicsItem. That didn't work and the background of the image is still gray instead of transparent. If you can't figure out what's wrong with this code can someone please post or link me to an example of how to display an image with a transparent background using QGraphicsScene?  Here is the original code, followed by the QGraphicsItem code, followed by my main function.

```
#include "headers/piece.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QBitmap>
#include <QCursor>
using namespace std;

Piece::Piece(string color, string piece, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    this->piece = piece;
    this->color = color;
    this->setMaximumHeight(36);
    this->setMaximumWidth(36);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    setMouseTracking(false);
}

void Piece::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    string image = ":/images/" + color + piece + ".png";
    pixmap.load(image.c_str());
    //pixmap.setMask(pixmap.createMaskFromColor(QColor(240, 240, 240)));

    QPainter paint(this);
    paint.drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap);
}

void Piece::setPosition(int file, int rank)
{
    pixmap.load(":/images/whitepawn.png");
    QImage image = pixmap.toImage();
    x = (file-1)*50 + 18;// - image.width()/2;
    y = (rank-1)*50 + 18;// - image.height()/2;
    move(x, y);
}

void Piece::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
    x = event->globalX()-18;
    y = event->globalY()-18;
    move(x,y);
    }
}
```

.

```
#include "piece2.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QBitmap>
#include <QCursor>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
using namespace std;

Piece2::Piece2(string color, string piece, QObject *parent) :
    QGraphicsItem()
{
    this->piece = piece;
    this->color = color;
    //this->setMaximumHeight(36);
    //this->setMaximumWidth(36);
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    //setMouseTracking(false);
}

void Piece2::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    string image = ":/images/" + color + piece + ".png";
    pixmap.load(image.c_str());
    //pixmap.setMask(pixmap.createMaskFromColor(QColor(240, 240, 240)));

    //QPainter paint(this);
    painter->drawPixmap(0, 0, pixmap);
}

void Piece2::setPosition(int file, int rank)
{
    pixmap.load(":/images/whitepawn.png");
    QImage image = pixmap.toImage();
    x = (file-1)*50 + 18;// - image.width()/2;
    y = (rank-1)*50 + 18;// - image.height()/2;
    setPos(x, y);
}

void Piece2::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton)
    {
//  x = event->globalX()-18;
//  y = event->globalY()-18;
    setPos(x,y);
    }
}
```

.

```
#include <QtGui>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include "headers/board.h"
#include "headers/pawn.h"
#include "headers/knight.h"
#include "headers/bishop.h"
#include "headers/rook.h"
#include "headers/king.h"
#include "headers/queen.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
    Board board;

    scene->addWidget(&board);
    scene->addWidget(board.pawn2);
    board.pawn2->setPosition(1,1);

    //view->viewport()->setPalette(QColor(Qt::transparent));
    //view->viewport()->setAutoFillBackground(false);
    view->setScene(scene);
    //view->setBackgroundRole(QPalette::NoRole);
    view->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you try using a stylesheet to set the background transparency?

```
yourWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;");
```

Comment: Wow... I could have sworn I had tried this. I probably had messed up the parameter. Anyway, thank you, this problem had halted my progress for a week! I don't know why this isn't a default setting though, it seems like layouts make it transparent by default, this should too.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm your problem. Additional, laurents solution can't work in Linux. But for me worked next action:

Before put your QWidget to QGraphicsScene by addWidget() method, set him next flag:

```
board->setAttribute( Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground );
```

Detailed explanation is here (ru): https://webhamster.ru/mytetrashare/index/mtb0/1625823664d5m6pmpy7s