# How to visualize a QPushButton after hovering on a QLabel

Tags: c++11, qt5, popupwindow, qcombobox, qlabel

How do I visualize a `QPushButton` after hovering on a `QLabel`?

Given a very simple user interface composed of a `QLabel` and a `QComboBox` shown below:

[image: vis1]

The user clicks on the `QComboBox` below (promoted as `QPixmapComboBox`), and a list of colors shows up. The user clicks one of this color and a `QPixmapPopUp` shows up. This `QPixmapPopUp` is also sub-classed as a `QLabel` to allow the override of the `paintEvent`. The popup shows up and after you hover on it it changes color. It was very difficult to arrive to this point for the small verifiable example. **Problem:** But now I got stuck because as I hover the popup, I have been trying to understand how to show two push button. Those buttons should also disappear as the user does not hover anymore on the popup. For completeness the whole minimal verifiable example can also be downloaded from [here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/popupwindow/src/master/) if needed:

Below the current behavior and the expected behavior:

**Current Behavior:**

[image: vis2]

**Expected Behavior:**

[image: vis3]

Below the most important part of the code where the animation and the paint event is taken care of:
**qpixmappopup.h**

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QVariantAnimation>
#include <QStyleOptionButton>
#include <QStylePainter>
#include <QEvent>

class QPixmapPopUp : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QPixmapPopUp(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    void show(int msecs = 3000);

signals:
    void clicked();

protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) override;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override;
    
private:
    QTimer *mTimer;
    void animateHover(bool in);
    QVariantAnimation *m_transition;
    int m_duration;
    QColor m_currentColor;

};
```

**qpixmappopup.cpp**

```
#include "qpixmappopup.h"
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QStyleOptionButton>

QPixmapPopUp::QPixmapPopUp(QWidget *parent)
    : QLabel { parent }
{
    setFrameShape(QLabel::Box);
    setWindowFlag(Qt::Popup);
    setFocusPolicy(Qt::WheelFocus);
    mTimer = new QTimer(this);
    mTimer->setSingleShot(true);
    connect(mTimer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &QLabel::hide);
}

void QPixmapPopUp::show(int msecs)
{
    QLabel::show();
    mTimer->start(msecs);
}

void QPixmapPopUp::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    emit clicked();
    hide();
    QLabel::mousePressEvent(e);
}

void QPixmapPopUp::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStylePainter painter(this);
    QStyleOptionButton option;
    QPalette p(palette());
    option.state |= QStyle::State_MouseOver;

}

void QPixmapPopUp::animateHover(bool in)
{
    const QColor &baseColor(palette().brush(QPalette::Light).color());
    const QColor &highlightColor(palette().brush(QPalette::Highlight).color());
    QColor startValue(in ? baseColor : highlightColor);

    if (m_transition) {
        startValue = m_transition->currentValue().value<QColor>();
        m_transition->stop();
    }

    m_transition = new QVariantAnimation(this);

    m_transition->setStartValue(startValue);
    m_transition->setEndValue(in ? highlightColor : baseColor);
    m_transition->setDuration(m_duration);

    connect(m_transition, &QVariantAnimation::valueChanged, [this](const QVariant &value){
        m_currentColor = value.value<QColor>();
        repaint();
    });

    connect(m_transition, &QVariantAnimation::destroyed, [this](){
        m_transition = nullptr;
    });

    m_transition->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}
```

I have been doing extensive research on how to solve this problem and consulted [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635760/changing-mouse-cursor-in-a-qobject-qgraphicsitem-inherited-class) which was good because it explained how the hovering should or should not occur.

I moved initially to re-implementation of the protected memebers `void enterEvent(QEvent *ev) override` and `void leaveEvent(QEvent *ev) override` found in [this source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729040/how-to-create-qt-label-hover-effect/40730874), and thought it could have been a good idea moving in that direction. But after a bit of trial-error I arrived nowhere.

I tried to search as much as possible a possible solution in the official documentation of `Qt5` but didn't really find any useful lead on how to move on from here.

Please if anyone had the same problem, point to the right solution on how to solve this issue as of now I don't have any additional idea on how to move on.

Comment: Do these buttons really have to lie outside of the QPixmapPopup? To which layout do these buttons belong to?

Comment: Hi and thanks for stopping by and reading the question. Yes, the preferred behavior is that those button should lie outside of the QPixmapPopUp because they will be used to interact with the QPixmapPopUp (like rotating the QPixmapPopUp, zooming etc).

Comment: Alternatively, you could base your approach on QML which offers some more flexibility in customized and animated GUIs. [Here](https://techbase.kde.org/Reusable_QML_components) an example I've found for an animated popup. But I presume this would require quite drastic changes to your project.

Comment: Eventually the QPixmapPopUp will be used to upload images. That is why those button should be outside of that

Comment: Thanks for the source :) , but unfortunately for this project I can't use QML. So far this is the best small verifiable example I came up with and it took me a lot of time and efforts to replicate the problem. In the question I attached a link to my Bitbucket to download the source code if any users want to see that too.

Comment: Reading your question, it seems that the problem is that the buttons btn1 and btn2 are not shown. But where in your code are the buttons created? Which is their parent? The buttons cannot float simply on top of the GUI, they must be added to some layout. I think you require some parent container for this popup and all other elements that should be displayed. Maybe a [QGraphicsView with transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238027) could be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219019/discussion-between-normanius-and-emanuele).